# Order by desc in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following query:

`SELECT u.first_name, o.created_at
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN order AS o ON o.user_id =  u.id
GROUP BY u.id`

The data structure looks like this:

`user 1`

- `order 1`
  `order 2`
  `order 3`

`user 2`

- `order 1`

`user 3`

- `order 1` `order 2`

`user 4`

- `order 1` `order 2` `order 3` `order 4` `order 5`

Currently the query is returning data as follow:

`user 1` `>` `order 1`

`user 2` `>` `order 1`

`user 3` `>` `order 1`

`user 4` `>` `order 1`

but I would like to have all last items of user order, as example below:

`user 1` `>` `order 3`

`user 2` `>` `order 1`

`user 3` `>` `order 2`

`user 4` `>` `order 5`

Is there a way to get this nicely?
I need to retrieve last order of each user to generate the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :-

```
SELECT u.first_name, o.created_at
FROM user AS u
INNER JOIN order AS o ON o.user_id =  u.id
Where o.created_at=(SELECT MAX(o2.created_at)
                    FROM order o2
                    WHERE o.user_id =  o2.user_id);
GROUP BY u.id
```

this  `SELECT MAX(o2.created_at)` use for get MAX `created_at`

Comment: I think it should be WHERE o.user_id =  o2.user_id in SELECT of o.created_at because only then it returns proper results, correct?

Comment: yes ...sorry my mistake i update my answer  @GrzegorzTomasiak

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.first_name, max(o.created_at) as max_created_at
FROM user u
INNER JOIN order AS o ON o.user_id =  u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: This works for simple query but if I have more inner joins like, e.g. which shop order came from then it is joining wrong shop (from the first order, not last)

Comment: @grzegorz Ask a different question, get a different answer.